# Laravel Artisan Command and Repository Datatype Checking

Tags: php, oop, laravel, repository

I'm looking for help implementing some best practices on a small Laravel 4 project I'm working on. My snippets below are simplified to help get across what I'm trying to understand.

---

**Note Repository Snippet**:

```
...

public function deleteNotesOlderThan($days)
{
    if (!is_int($days)) {
        /* @TODO - Something here and return error possibly NULL? */
    }

    $date = new \Carbon\Carbon();
    $date = $date->subDays($days);
    Note::where('created_at', "<", $date)->delete();
}

...
```

I'm injecting this particular repository in Controllers and Artisan commands. My question has to do with checking the datatype of the argument $days and returning errors in the correct places. If $days is not an int, what type of error should I return that can be utilized in Controllers and Commands I'm injecting into? See my Command below.

---

**Note Artisan Command:**

```
public function fire()
{
    $days = $this->option('days');

    if (!$days) {
        $days = 30;
    }

    if(!is_int($days)) {
        $this->error("Failure - The 'Days' option must be a valid integer");
        return false;
    }

    // $this->note is being injected into command via construct
    $this->note->deleteNotesOlderThan($days);

    $this->info('Success - Notes older than ' . $days . ' days(s) have been deleted.');
}
```

As you can see in my Command, I'm checking to make sure $days is an integer again. I guess my question is, what would be the best practice here. If I'm executing $this->note->deleteNotesOlderThan($days) and that particular method is already making sure $days is an int, what's the best way of giving an error but DRYing things up? I hope this makes sense.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function,

```
    public function deleteNotesOlderThan($days)
    {
        if (!is_int($days)) {
            return FALSE;
        }

        $date = new \Carbon\Carbon();
        $date = $date->subDays($days);
        Note::where('created_at', "<", $date)->delete();
        return TRUE;

    }
```

And in the artisan command,

---

```
        public function fire()
        {
            $days = $this->option('days');            
            if (!$days) {
                $days = 30;
            }       
            if($this->note->deleteNotesOlderThan($days)){
                $this->info('Success - Notes older than ' . $days . ' days(s) have been deleted.');
            }else{
                 $this->error("Failure - The 'Days' option must be a valid integer");
            }                   
        }
```

This is what I would do.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up going with something like this.